# Sonar failure in gradle5 with SourceSetOutput.getClassesDir not found

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

I am getting an error while running sonarqube on gradle 5, the error I am getting is

```
What went wrong:
 org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput.getClassesDir()Ljava/io/File;


Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with     --scan to get full insights.

Exception is:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:        
    org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput.getClassesDir()Ljava/io/File;
at    org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubePlugin.configureSourceDirsAndJavaClasspath(SonarQubePlugin.java:169)
at    org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubePlugin.lambda$configureForJava$1(SonarQubePlugin.java:104)
```

I tried downgrading the gradle version to 4.0 and found out the issue, now it is showing

```
:sonarqube
Gradle now uses separate output directories for each JVM language, but this build assumes a single directory for all classes from a source set. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0
    at     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetOutput.getClassesDir(DefaultSourceSetOutput.java:79)
at    org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetOutput_Decorated.getClassesDir(Unknown Source)
at  org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubePlugin.configureSourceDirsAndJavaClasspath(SonarQubePlugin.java:169)
```

Gradle configurations present in my code is as below,

```
sonarqube {

    properties {
        property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "${project.buildDir}/jacoco/test.exec"
        property "sonar.exclusions", "**/generated-*/**/*"
        property "sonar.sources", "src/main/java"
        property "sonar.tests", "src/test/java"
        //property "sonar.java.binaries", "${project.buildDir}/classes/main/"
    }
}
```

I believe the issue can be fixed by either adding an expected property to the sonarqube property list or explicitly setting the source directory. Can anyone please advice on how to do that?

Answer (score 9):

I use Gradle 5.1 and I observed the same using org.sonarqube:2.5. However, it works for me when I use org.sonarqube:2.7.

```
plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.7"
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why this has not been accepted as the answer, but it did solve the issue for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I used `Gradle 5.3`, I am getting the errors as in this question. Then I downgrade to `Gradle 4.10.3`. It worked like magic.

Answer (score -1):

Not a complete solution, I migrated my build script to kotlin, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921605/unable-to-exclude-generated-classes-from-kotlin-jacoco-test-coverage/55953573#55953573) helped me.