# Unable to Exclude generated classes from kotlin jacoco test coverage

Tags: kotlin, build.gradle

I am trying to exclude some generated classes from jacoco coverage report. Which is working fine with groovy but after converting to Kotlin it's not working

```
tasks.withType<JacocoCoverageVerification> {
afterEvaluate {
     files(classDirectories.files.forEach() {
        fileTree(it).apply {
            exclude("com/generate/**")
        }
    })
}
violationRules {
    rule {
        limit {
            minimum = BigDecimal(0.30)
        }

    }

}
```

}

```
tasks.getByName("check")
.dependsOn(tasks.getByName("jacocoTestCoverageVerification"))
```

But violation rule working perfectly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is a limitaion with `jacoco plugin` on `kotlin`. Since the `classDirectories` is not final, we cant go with the old way. We need to use the method `classDirectories.setFrom` to set the value.

```
tasks.withType<JacocoCoverageVerification> {
    violationRules {
        rule {
            limit {
                minimum = BigDecimal(0.62)
            }
        }
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.map {
            fileTree(it).apply {
                exclude("com/generate/**")
            }
        }))
    }
}

tasks.withType<JacocoReport> {
    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.map {
            fileTree(it).apply {
                exclude("com/generate/**")
            }
        }))
    }
}
```

Comment: amazing...was looking for an answer for quite a while....this one works...thx

Answer (score 1):

For excluding classes in jacoco report in Kotlin dsl remember to use `setExcludes` instead of `exclude`

```
tasks.jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        html.required.set(true)
        xml.required.set(true)
    }
    classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.map {
        fileTree(it) {
            setExcludes(listOf(
                    "**/first/path/to/skip/*.class",
                    "**/second/path/to/skip/*.class"
            ))
        }
    }))
}
```