# Gradle build console output for jacoco says it's lower % than it really is

Tags: gradle, kotlin, code-coverage, jacoco

I'm trying to do a gradle build with jacoco, but it's failing because the coverage is lower than "expected". But when I open the generated HTML file, it's actually higher than my set minimum.

I've tried excluding more files from being analyzed, but it didn't help.

```
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.4"
//    applyTo test
}

jacocoTestReport.dependsOn(test)

// this just ensures it runs with for build, but not for non-builds (like tests)
build {
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport

    // this will do checks on the violations + fail build if there's too little coverage
    finalizedBy jacocoTestCoverageVerification
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        csv.enabled false
        xml.enabled false
        html.enabled true

        // setting the output location for html stuff
        html.destination file("${buildDir}/reports/jacoco")
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude: [...files...])
        }))
    }
}

jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    violationRules {
        rule {
            limit {
                // % in decimal form for when build should fail
                minimum = 0.75
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I get in my build says: instructions covered ratio is 0.74, but expected minimum is 0.75

But as you can see in https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxGUP.png it's 80%. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class exclusions are probably not getting applied to the jacocoTestCoverageVerification task.

Have you tried applying the exclusion in the jacocoTestCoverageVerification task as well?

```
jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    violationRules {
        rule {
            limit {
                // % in decimal form for when build should fail
                minimum = 0.75
            }
        }
    }

    afterEvaluate {
            classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
                fileTree(dir: it, exclude: [...files...])
            }))
        }
    }
}
```

Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55953573/7105883

Comment: A funny phenomena: So I set my min to 0.99 to see if it helps.
With it in jacocoTestReport, it says 0.79 coverage, but the HTML file says 80%. With it in jacocoTestCoverageVerification, it says coverage is 0.8, but the HTML file says 79% (files aren't excluded). Duplicating it in both of them puts them in agreement... thanks, your suggestion did the trick!