# Exclude from coverage on multimodule project using jacoco and gradle

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, jacoco, multi-module

I've been trying to exclude certain classes and/or packages from the coverage report generated by **jacoco**. I've worked with jacoco before but it wasn't a multi-module project, so I tried translating the configuration and export it to the modules, but so far the report comes back completely ignoring my exclusion path.

I tried many solutions like:

- [Filter JaCoCo coverage reports with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887805/filter-jacoco-coverage-reports-with-gradle)
- https://gist.github.com/aalmiray/e6f54aa4b3803be0bcac
- [Unable to Exclude generated classes from kotlin jacoco test coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921605/unable-to-exclude-generated-classes-from-kotlin-jacoco-test-coverage)
- https://github.com/th-deng/jacoco-on-gradle-sample/blob/master/build.gradle.kts
- https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/issues/1176#issuecomment-435816812 <- which is the latest tried I made.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I'm not very knowledgable on gradle and almost every documentation/example I find uses a single module project.
I created a small project and pushed to [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/dbetancourt/kotlinmultimodule) so you can have a better look.

The desired result would be to be able to add more paths or classes to modules directly.

I would really appreciate any help you can provide.

---

Code snippets:

### [Root build.gradle.kts](https://gitlab.com/dbetancourt/kotlinmultimodule/-/blob/master/build.gradle.kts)

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.71"
    jacoco
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

defaultTasks("clean", "build", "test")

allprojects {
    apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
    apply(plugin = "jacoco")

    group = "org.example"
    version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    jacoco {
        toolVersion = "0.8.5"
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
        testImplementation("org.testng:testng:6.14.3")
    }

    configure<JavaPluginConvention> {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinJvmCompile::class) {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }

    tasks.test {
        useTestNG()
        finalizedBy("jacocoTestReport")
    }
}

tasks.jacocoTestReport {
    val sourceDirs = sourceSets.main.get().allSource.srcDirs
    additionalSourceDirs.setFrom(sourceDirs)
    sourceDirectories.setFrom(sourceDirs)
    classDirectories.setFrom(sourceSets.main.get().output)
    reports {
        html.isEnabled = true
        xml.isEnabled = false
        csv.isEnabled = false
    }
}

tasks.register<JacocoReport>("jacocoRootReport") {
    val sourceDirs = subprojects.map { project -> project.sourceSets.main.get().allSource.srcDirs }
    dependsOn(subprojects.map { project -> project.tasks.test })
    sourceDirectories.setFrom(sourceDirs)
    additionalSourceDirs.setFrom(sourceDirs)
    classDirectories.setFrom(subprojects.map { project -> project.sourceSets.main.get().output })
    executionData.setFrom(subprojects.map { project -> project.tasks.jacocoTestReport.get().executionData })
    reports {
        html.isEnabled = true
        xml.isEnabled = false
        csv.isEnabled = false
    }
}

tasks.test {
    finalizedBy("jacocoRootReport")
}
```

### [Module build.gradle.kts](https://gitlab.com/dbetancourt/kotlinmultimodule/-/blob/master/app/build.gradle.kts)

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":api"))
}

tasks {
    getByName<JacocoReport>("jacocoTestReport") {
        afterEvaluate {
            classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.map {
                fileTree(it) {
                    exclude("org/example/AppClass.class")
                }
            }))
        }
    }
}
```

Also, any feedback regarding anything else is highly appreciate it, I'm trying to learn/improve and could use some :).

[Edit #1] Just added a [singlemodule branch](https://gitlab.com/dbetancourt/kotlinmultimodule/-/tree/singlemodule) to the same repo in which is working as intended, but in a single module mode.

[Edit #2] Note I'm using `jacoco: 0.8.5` `gradle: 6.1` with the configuration files on `Kotlin DSL (build.gradle.kts)`

Answer (score 3):

Some time ago I also was stuck on the process of setting up JaCoCo with Sonarqube and came up with [this article](https://medium.com/@azizbekian/setup-jacoco-sonarqube-in-multimodule-multiflavor-kotlin-android-project-d8e7b27aed36) which might help you.

Here's the full content of `jacoco.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

tasks.withType(Test) {
    jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true
    jacoco.excludes = ['jdk.internal.*'] // see related issue https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/5184#issuecomment-457865951
}

tasks.withType(Test) { jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true }

project.afterEvaluate {

    (android.hasProperty('applicationVariants')
            ? android.'applicationVariants'
            : android.'libraryVariants').all { variant ->
        def variantName = variant.name
        def unitTestTask = "test${variantName.capitalize()}UnitTest"
        def uiTestCoverageTask = "create${variantName.capitalize()}CoverageReport"

        tasks.create(name: "${unitTestTask}Coverage", type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: [
                "$unitTestTask",
                "$uiTestCoverageTask",
                ":module1:testDebugUnitTest",
                ":module2:testDebugUnitTest",
                ":moduleN:testDebugUnitTest",
        ]) {
            group = "Reporting"
            description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports for the ${variantName.capitalize()} build"

            reports {
                html.enabled = true
                xml.enabled = true
                csv.enabled = false
            }

            def fileFilter = [
                    '**/R.class',
                    '**/R$*.class',
                    '**/BuildConfig.*',
                    '**/Manifest*.*',
                    '**/*Test*.*',
                    '**/com/example/databinding/*',
                    '**/com/example/generated/callback/*',
                    '**/android/databinding/*',
                    '**/androidx/databinding/*',
                    '**/di/module/*',
                    '**/*MapperImpl*.*',
                    '**/*$ViewInjector*.*',
                    '**/*$ViewBinder*.*',
                    '**/BuildConfig.*',
                    '**/*Component*.*',
                    '**/*BR*.*',
                    '**/Manifest*.*',
                    '**/*$Lambda$*.*',
                    '**/*Companion*.*',
                    '**/*Module.*', /* filtering Dagger modules classes */
                    '**/*Dagger*.*',/* filtering Dagger-generated classes */
                    '**/*MembersInjector*.*',
                    '**/*_Factory*.*',
                    '**/*_Provide*Factory*.*',
                    '**/*Extensions*.*',
                    '**/*$Result.*', /* filtering `sealed` and `data` classes */
                    '**/*$Result$*.*'/* filtering `sealed` and `data` classes */
                    '**/*Args*.*', /* filtering Navigation Component generated classes */
                    '**/*Directions*.*' /* filtering Navigation Component generated classes */
            ]

            classDirectories.setFrom(files([
                    fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes/${variantName}", excludes: fileFilter),
                    fileTree(dir: "$project.rootDir/module1/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter),
                    fileTree(dir: "$project.rootDir/module2/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter),
                    fileTree(dir: "$project.rootDir/moduleN/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter),
            ]))

            def coverageSourceDirs = [
                    "$project.rootDir/app/src/main/java",
                    "$project.projectDir/src/${variantName}/java",
                    "$project.rootDir/module1/src/main/java",
                    "$project.rootDir/module2/src/main/java",
                    "$project.rootDir/moduleN/src/main/java"
            ]
            additionalSourceDirs.setFrom(files(coverageSourceDirs))
            sourceDirectories.setFrom(files(coverageSourceDirs))

            def uiTestsData = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/outputs/code_coverage/${variantName}AndroidTest/connected/", includes: ["**/*.ec"])

            executionData(files([
                    "$project.buildDir/jacoco/${unitTestTask}.exec",
                    uiTestsData,
                    "$project.rootDir/module1/build/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec",
                    "$project.rootDir/module2/build/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec",
                    "$project.rootDir/moduleN/build/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec"
            ]))
        }
    }
}
```

You can examine `fileFilter` for further filtering options.

Then inside each module you have to import the `jacoco.gradle` as such:

```
apply from: "jacoco.gradle"
```

Comment: Cool! I'll git it a try! thank you very much for the reply :)